# Is a faithfully flat map of affine schemes open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness, open-map

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$

Let $R \rightarrow S$ be a faithfully flat (unital) homomorphism of commutative rings.  Does it follow that the corresponding map of topological spaces $\Spec S \twoheadrightarrow \Spec R$ is open?

<s>If not, is there a counterexample where both $R$ and $S$ are finitely generated over the same algebraically closed field?</s>

EDIT: The second question was answered in a comment, but I'm still interested in the first part.

Comment: If $R \to S$ is flat and of finite presentation, then $\operatorname{Spec}(f)$ is open (see \[Stacks, Tag [00I1](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I1)\]). The idea is that Chevalley's theorem implies the image of $\operatorname{Spec}(S)$ in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is constructible, and flat maps satisfy going down, hence the image is stable under generization.

Comment: Oh right; of course.  Well that answers the second part of my question.  Any ideas on the first part?  For that, if I remove "faithfully", then a counterexample is given by embedding any non-field integral domain into its fraction field.

Comment: As you said, $R\rightarrow\operatorname{Frac}R$ is not faithful. But $R\rightarrow R\times\operatorname{Frac}R$ is, and $\operatorname{Spec}(R\times\operatorname{Frac}R)=\operatorname{Spec}R\coprod\operatorname{Spec}\operatorname{Frac}R\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}R$ is not open.

Comment: @Roland Great; thanks! If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ..though now I wonder if there's a counterexample that is a local homomorphism of local rings.